# Tic-Tac-Toe MiniMax implementation always returns first free spot

Tags: javascript, minimax

I'm trying to implement Minimax to find the best move each turn in tic-tac-toe in js.

However, it always returns the first free spot: 0,0 and when this spot is taken 0,1 and so on.
It turns out that the miniMax function always returns 1.

```
let board = [
    ['', '', ''],
    ['', '', ''],
    ['', '', '']
];

const scores = {
    'X': 1,
    'O': -1
}

function miniMax(board, isMaximizing, player, turns) {
    let winner = checkForWinner(board);
    if (winner != null)
        return scores[winner];
    if (turns > 9)
        return 0;

    let bestScore = isMaximizing ? -Infinity : Infinity;
    let score;

    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            if (board[i][j] == '') {
                board[i][j] = player;
                score = miniMax(board, !isMaximizing, isMaximizing ? p2 : p1, turns + 1)[1];
                board[i][j] = '';
                if (isMaximizing) {
                    if (score > bestScore) {
                        bestScore = score;
                        bestMove = [i, j];
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if (score < bestScore) {
                        bestScore = score;
                        bestMove = [i, j];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return [bestMove, bestScore];
}
```

I've tried looking at other people's implementation of Minimax for Tic-Tac-Toe, but I couldn't understand what makes mine fail.

What did I do wrong?

**EDIT:** I've updated my code but now it returns 0,0 then 1,0 then 0,1 then 2,0 then 0,2.

Answer (score 1):

I see 2 problems with your minimax (negamax) code:

'1. In your minimax function you are going through each square finding the best move to make. However you are only returning the score, not the best move. If you find a winning move, then write this:

```
return None, 1
```

Then in your minimax recursive call you write:

```
miniMax(board, !isMaximizing, isMaximizing ? p2 : p1, turns + 1)[1]
```

At the bottom return you write:

```
return bestMove, bestScore
```

Where you decide the bestScore you also need to update the bestMove, ONLY IF the maximum/minimum score changes. Similar to what you do in the bestMove function.

'2. In your bestMove function you are going through all the squares AGAIN. This is what makes it return the same square over and over. Since your minimax will find the best move you only need to make the initial call:

```
bestMove, bestScore = miniMax(board, !isMaximizing, isMaximizing ? p2 : p1, turns + 1)
```

Otherwise it will go to the first square and do the complete minimax, therefore finding the best move for the position (regardless of starting move). Since it will never find a better move than the best move, it will not update the bestMove to anything else than the first possible square.

Hope I am making any sense, English is not my native language and I am only used to coding in Python :)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer!
I've tried what you said and I changed the minimax function, and I don't use the bestMove function, but it still doesn't work.
Now it returns 0,0 then 1,0 then 0,1 then 2,0 then 0,2.
What have I done wrong?

Comment: I couldn't write it in a comment... I will edit my question